# How to interpret python call signatures with nested lists

Tags: python

I have been looking at the documentation for the Python datetime library, and I am confused by the call signatures. For example, `datetime.timedelta` can be called in the following way

```
datetime.timedelta(10, 68400)
```

However, its call signature is documented as

```
datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

I am uncertain how to interpret the nested lists in the call signature, and how they relate to the ways in which you can call `timedelta`.

Comment: These arguments are optional therefore they are in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related answer here, and is basically a duplicate of your question: [What do square brackets, "[]", mean in function/class documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718903/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-function-class-documentation#1718913)

Either you can give the options in order, for example: timedelta(1, 2, 3) for 1 day, 2 seconds and 3 microseconds, or you specify by the arguments you're interested in: timedelta(days=1, microseconds=4) and this allows you to put them in any order, and/or omit the options you don't need.

Edit: OK I think this is the answer: [Why do Python function docs include the comma after the bracket for optional args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120507/why-do-python-function-docs-include-the-comma-after-the-bracket-for-optional-arg#2120518)

Comment: The implementation would just be timedelta(*args, **kwargs), yes? From your answer, I understand how to use "timedelta". However, why denote the signature with nested lists with leading commas? I don't understand the significance of that notation.

Comment: Agreed on timedelta(*args, **kwargs), unfortunately as to the point of your question that stumps me as well.